# Do the posts automatically change to community wikis!

Tags: discussion

In the past there was a feature where x amount of edits automatically turned posts into community wikis. Is this feature on for the beta? or did I accidentally make a post a community wiki. I thought that was globally turned off.

- [how do i accurately compute coverage of overlapping analytical curves](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/148/how-do-i-accurately-compute-coverage-of-overlapping-analytical-curves)

I dont think a site like this benefits from such rules anyway. Atleast it does not fit my style very well as i might add a few references, and thoughts later. I might also touchup code and add pictures.

Also what is our general policy on community wikis? I know many of the communities do not like the idea.

POst in question:

Comment: Making Community Wiki is a tick box, so it is fairly unlikely you would have done it accidentally. Could you include a link to the example post?

Comment: @trichoplax Done. Although, anything is possible when you use the mobile interface on a mobile Firefox. Which stackexhange does not recognize as existing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the automatic conversion to community wikis [was globally turned off](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228947/201409). But even before, I doubt it would kick in after 6 edits. So it seems you must have accidentally ticked the community wiki checkbox beneath the edit field:

[image]

If you don't actually want your answer to be community wiki, you can always flag your answer with a custom flag to ask a moderator to un-CW the post.